# qt как правильно сделать connect

Tags: qt

mainwindow:

```
ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(model->fieldIndex("attach"), new buttonDelegate(ui->tableView)); //кнопка в таблице делегат
```

далее сам делегат buttondelegate.cpp

```
bool buttonDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if( event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease )
    {
        QMouseEvent * e = (QMouseEvent *)event;
        int clickX = e->x();
        int clickY = e->y();

        QRect r = option.rect;
        int x,y,w,h;
        x = r.left() + r.width() - 30;
        y = r.top();
        w = 30;//ширина кнопки
        h = 30;//высота кнопки

        //если попали в кнопку
        if( clickX > x && clickX < x + w )
            if( clickY > y && clickY < y + h )
            {
                int row = index.row();
                emit createNewUpload(row);

            }
    }
}
```

по нажатию делегата должно открыться окно

```
void MainWindow::uploadFile(int row)
{
    uploadFile_window = new uploadFileForm();
    uploadFile_window->orderinfo(row);
    uploadFile_window->show();
}
```

ну и так далее

ВОПРОС как сделать connect при нажатии на делегат-кнопку. Ведь он еще не создан до нажатия. Ну и если это вообще не по "госту" как правильно.

```
connect(что тут писать?,SIGNAL(createNewUpload(int row)),this,SLOT(uploadFile(int row)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала создаем делегата, потом соединяем сигнал, примерно так:

```
buttonDelegate *delegate = new buttonDelegate(ui->tableView);
connect(delegate, SIGNAL(createNewUpload(int row)), this, SLOT(uploadFile(int row)));
ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(model->fieldIndex("attach"), delegate);
```

Comment: СПАСИБО помогло ).